# How do you fix weird margins in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, rendering

Sometimes I have really **weird margins in Chrome** that don't appear in any other browser and can only be experienced **on certain zoom levels** (actually I don't know what they are, they are not necessary margins, it cannot really be explained just from seeing the CSS).

To give you an example, I have this here, where there is a **tiny small white line at the bottom of the progress bar**, that shouldn't be there. In this case they occur on 100% zoom level, which makes it particularly annoying:

[image]

Or if you like JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/JakeTheDog/3muvv1Lx/1/

HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th class="text-center">Column 1</th>
    <th class="text-center">Column 2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="text-center">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" style="width:75%;"><span class="progress-bar-tooltip my-progress-bar-tooltip">75.1%</span></div>
        </div>
        <!--<span>Gut- (2.30)</span>-->
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" style="width:77.8%;"><span class="progress-bar-tooltip my-progress-bar-tooltip">77.8%</span></div>
        </div>
        <!--<span>Gut- (2,3)</span>-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.progress {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px #375D81;
  margin: 0;
}

.progress-bar {
  background-color: #375D81;
  span {}
}

td{
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

However, this is somewhat problematic, because it **seems to also have something to do with the screen resolution**. I have this line on my laptop screen, but not on a larger screen that I have also connected to my laptop.
You should be able to get the weird line though, if you play around with the zoom function of your browser.

I only have this issue in Chrome. I have never seen this in any other browser. So is this a Chrome bug? And is there a way to prevent these lines from occurring?

Edit: I use Chrome 61.0.3163.100 (64-Bit) on a Windows 10 Pro. My Laptop is a ThinkPad T540p. Resolution 1920x1080. Windows-Scaling on the screen is set to 125% (this only seems to influence on which zoom level of the browser the bug occurs).

Comment: I don't have this white 1px line in Chrome. Which OS are you using?

Comment: which version of chrome have you used...? because in my chrome there is no any white space.

Comment: See my edited comment.

Answer (score 0):

'{}' error in **.progress-bar {
  background-color: #375D81;
  span {}
}**

and add height:auto; in .progress-bar class

```css
.progress {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px #375D81;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.progress-bar {
  background-color: #375D81;
  height:auto;
 }


td{
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th class="text-center">Column 1</th>
    <th class="text-center">Column 2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="text-center">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" style="width:75%;"><span class="progress-bar-tooltip my-progress-bar-tooltip">75.1%</span></div>
        </div>
        <!--<span>Gut- (2.30)</span>-->
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" style="width:77.8%;"><span class="progress-bar-tooltip my-progress-bar-tooltip">77.8%</span></div>
        </div>
        <!--<span>Gut- (2,3)</span>-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ohh, I had this in it, because I copied it from my SCSS code, but it didn't cause the bug. Setting height to auto didn't fix it either.